# Julia - getting started with local compiled Pkg

Tags: package, julia, mathematical-optimization

This is on Julia 1.9.3. I'm trying to use the high precision arithmetic and the Remez.jl package to test out some ideas. I have the code and it compiles OK. I can do toy things in Julia as a language but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the compiled "Remez" local package visible to the julia environment to run the initial runtests.jl or to my code. This is the console output and I have looked at various suggestions on SO and tried them to no avail. I'm pretty sure this is a classic newbie error in the Julia environment but I just
haven't found the right FAQ.
Please can someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong here?

```
$ julia Remez.jl
$ julia runtests.jl
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Remez not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")` to install the Remez package.
Stacktrace:
[1] macro expansion
@ ./loading.jl:1630 [inlined]
[2] macro expansion
@ ./lock.jl:267 [inlined]
[3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
@ Base ./loading.jl:1611
in expression starting at /home/martin/Downloads/runtests.jl:1
$ import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Remez"'
$ Run 'import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")'
Command 'Run' not found, did you mean:
[snip]
$ import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Remez"'
$ using Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"Remez"'
$ import Pkg; Pkg.add(".Remez")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `".Remez"'
$ julia -v
julia version 1.9.3
```

And a few other permutations all with the same no-can-do result.
Thanks for the first answer I had hoped that it would fix things but unfortunately I still get exactly the same error message. I include the relevant Project.toms file below. I don't really understand how it works.

```
name = "Remez"
uuid = "2e7db186-766a-50e7-8928-5c30181fb135"
authors = ["Simon Byrne <redacted>"]
version = "0.1.1"

[compat]
julia = "1.0"

[extras]
Test = "8dfed614-e22c-5e08-85e1-65c5234f0b40"

[targets]
test = ["Test"]
```

Thanks for any enlightenment. I'm sure it is something really stupid

Comment: I recommend you read https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/. The first two commands that you issue, `julia name_of_file.jl`, will start julia, execute all the lines of code listed in the file, then exit julia and put you back into the shell you started from (in your case, bash). It appears this is not what you want to do. Run julia from the shell with the simple command `julia`, then start issuing commands to julia like `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")`.

Comment: @Paste Thanks for the hint. I have read the getting started guide. It is making the jump from a single self contained .jl toy executable to something which uses an external library that is giving me grief. Your suggestion was very helpful in terms of fixing the Pkg commands that were failing to work for me but in this new interactive state how do I compile and run the main executable? I hadn't spotted that I was back in bash and up until then julia sourcefile.jl as a simple command had worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, start julia with `julia`. This will lead you to be in a Julia terminal, recognisable by a `julia>` prompt.

From there you can first add your desired pachage: `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Remez")`.

This should install the Remez package in the default environment, and need to be done only once.
After that, you can import it with `using Remez` and use the functions that the package makes available.

Of course if you don't want to work in the teminal, you can use a development editor like VSCode with the Julia plugin (you still need to have Julia installed in your pc,  but this you already have).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Remez has now incorporated itself into the system and at the outer level "julia runtests.jl" now functions as expected. I'm still a bit confused about what I can and can't do from the julia  prompt though. The runtime environment feels a bit alien compared to other languages. Marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: The Julia prompt actually looks very similar to the R or Python prompt. The idea is that it is less common to perform analysis by running `julia myscript.jl` like you would do with compiled languages.. rather you interactively "play" with your code, but of course when you are done you can run `julia myscript.jl`.. Inside `myscript.jl` you will have some sections with `using Package A , Package B, ...` and then your code that benefits of the functionalities of these packages. There is another point on using environments in Julia, but this is another question..

Answer (score 0):

You need `julia --project=.. runtests.jl`. The `project` environment tells julia where the `Project.toml` file that specifies dependencies is located.